how to give the pipelines permanently access to new securefiles uploaded?
We are using azuredevops securefiles to update the secret values in Azure keyvault and created the same. we are using parametrized value for our securfile as we have to use this between different teams, and because of this we are using some naming pattern and each applications should follow the same each time they want to update the secret , also the secure file is not giving option to allow its content for next execution, we have to delete the existing secure file and need to upload secure file with same name by changing the value in it.
because of this, whenever we are trying to execute the pipeline, its asking for granting the permission for pipeline onto the securefile and which is manually need to do. Any dolution here?

Updating the disucussions in the answer that I am afraid there is no built-in functionality to set pipelines permission dynamically to have all the newly uploaded secure files inherit those settings.
Since the resources permissions are checked at stage level, you may consider adding a stage: Preparation with the PowerShell script below to assign the current pipeline with the permission to use a secure file. Here is the API that the script calls.
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  testSecureFile: testSecureFile.json

stages:
- stage: Preparation
  jobs:
  - job: PreparePipelinePermissionsForSecureFile
    displayName: Grant permission for current pipeline to consume ${{ variables.testSecureFile }}
    steps:
    - pwsh: |
        $headers = @{
            'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + '$(System.AccessToken)'
            'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
        }

        $secureFileURL = "$(System.CollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/distributedtask/securefiles?api-version=6.0-preview.1"

        $secureFiles = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $secureFileURL -Headers $headers
        $testSecureFile = $secureFiles.value | Where-Object { $_.name -eq "$(testSecureFile)" }

        if ($testSecureFile) {
            $secureFileId = $testSecureFile.id
            Write-Output "Secure file ID: $secureFileId"
        } else {
            Write-Output "Secure file 'testSecureFile.json' not found."
        }

        $URL = "$(System.CollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/pipelines/pipelinepermissions?api-version=7.2-preview.1"

        $body = @(
            @{
                "resource" = @{
                    "type" = "securefile"
                    "id" = "$secureFileId"
                }
                "pipelines" = @(
                    @{
                        "authorized" = $true
                        "id" = $(System.DefinitionId)
                    }
                )
            }
        )

        # $body = @(
        #     @{
        #         "resource" = @{
        #             "type" = "securefile"
        #             "id" = "$secureFileId"
        #         }
        #         "allPipelines" = @{
        #             "authorized" = $true
        #         }
        #     }
        # )

        $jsonBody = ConvertTo-Json($body) -Depth 10
        $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -Uri $URL -Headers $headers -Body $jsonBody
        $response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

- stage: UseSecureFileInDownstreamStage
  jobs:
  - job: UseSecureFile
    displayName: Download secure file - ${{ variables.testSecureFile }}
    steps:
    - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
      inputs:
        secureFile: '$(testSecureFile)'


Before running a pipeline to consume the secure file that is newly uploaded, you may Edit the Pipeline permissions for this secure file.

You may either grant permissions for a selection of pipeline(s) to use this resource or open access to all pipelines.
Besides, even though the secure files in each upload share the same name, once uploaded to Azure Pipelines Library, they will be considered as different resources with different secureFileIds in the URL. Since they are considered as different resources without any pipeline permissions compared to the previous version, we will have to reassign permissions for the new secure file resources.

Yes,already aware of this. But there is no way to add this dynamically ?

As far as I know, there is no built-in functionality to set pipelines permission to have all the newly uploaded secure files inherit those settings. This API also requires us to know the resource id first.

Hi @Vowneee, Would you consider adding a new stage to call API and update pipeline permission? Hope the updated answer may help resolve your concern in this post.

Thanks.. this solution worked for us. But one issue we are facing is only the person who uploaded the secretfile only getting the access to delete the secure file added and its blocking others to add securefile with same name(here we have condition to satisfy the secretfile name). So how we can ensure that the secretfile is deleted after the creation of secret creation pipeline  for that specific secretfile.

The two files with the same name should have different secureFileIds, which are GUIDs. By the way, may I ask how you upload the new secure file, like manually in the web UI? If you have difficulty in getting the secure file ids, please feel welcome to post in a new thread, where we can discuss on more details. Thx for the time and have a productive week ahead.

I added from web UI. and pipeline executed successfully. But When another team mate want to add the secretfile with same filename.. they are not able to add new file with same name as the old one still existing there. When they are trying to delete the file also its giving error as only uploaded person is having the access to the previous added secretfile.

Was the team mate inherited the Administrator role of the secure file? They may check the Security settings for all secure files and the specific one.
